# Why isnt the backgrounds showing on iphone/ipad?

Tags: css, background

I am aware that there are a lot of other issues than this, but right now I just need to know why the backgrounds on the homepage aren't showing on iPhone/iPad?

The site is baardk.com.

Comment: Voting to delete, far too localised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a CSS `background` on the `img` tag, I'm not sure if this is supported on iOS.

One solution that I am pretty sure will work is using the following CSS applied to the wrapping `a` tags instead:

```
div.pure-g-r a{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

div.gano-box a{
 background: -default image here-;
}
div.gano-box a:hover{
 background: -hover image here-;
}
/*... for all your other boxes*/
```

Another suggestion: rather use an HTML colour code for your coloured backgrounds. This will improve loading speed and performance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, i tried using html color for this, but the problem is, i need the icon to stay on top at all times, as well as being centered (on hover also). Is there any way that i can work my way around this?

Comment: You are using an image for the icon so it should stay centered. I tested my code in Chrome and it works exactly same as your code. I couldn't test it on my iPad though as it doesn't have a console.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You don't know how much i appreciate this, man. Worked out great!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked! Good luck for your exam.